# How can I display data from the current hour of data collection from my Django database using Chart.js on my frontend canvas?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have an issue displaying data from the current hour of data collection from my django database to my frontend Chart.js . (See code below)

I have tried what I found with datetime.now() queries below:

#1. This block is the one I am trying to fix

```
from datetime import datetime

def datapage(request
 now = datetime.now() 
 print(now.day) # to check current day output
 print(now.hour) # to check current hour output

 # Storing appends
 labels = []
 data = []

 queryset = Object.objects.filter(datefield__day=now.day, datefield__hour=now.hour)
 for entry in queryset:
  labels.append(entry.date.strftime('Hour %H'))
  data.append(entry.Datafield)

 return render(request, 'datapage.html', {
  'labels': labels,
  'data': data,
 })
```

#2 This is the compromise I made but it would display rather the current day's data

```
# Modifying this line
queryset = Object.objects.filter(datefield__day=now.day, datefield__hour__lte=now.hour)
```

For Context, here's my script on the chart in the frontend,

```
<body>
<div class="flex w-full justify-around g-4">
          <div class="w-1/2 shadow-md rounded-lg">
            <div class="py-3 px-5 bg-gray-50">
              Total Environmental Temperature
            </div>
            <canvas class="p-10" id="barChart1"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>

<script>
const barData = {
      labels: {{labels|safe}},
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Bar Dataset',
          backgroundColor: "rgb(34 211 238)",
          borderColor: "rgb(34 211 238)",
          data: {{data|safe}},
        },
      ],
    };

    const barConfig = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: barData,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Sample Bar Chart'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const barChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById("barChart1"),
      barConfig
    )
</script>
```

Overall, an empty chart is generated when I use datefield__hour or datefield__hour__gte, and only the __lte works.

[Empty Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7LDD.png)
[datefield__hour__lte Resulting Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxbeV.png)